# Netezza external table dataobject

Tags: netezza

How does DATAOBJECT & REMOTESOURCE options work… In our environment we have the Netezza host and a separate Linux ‘script-host’ where we keep most of the scripts used in the ETL process as well as some pipe-delimited flat files that we load using some utility.

With C:\ we are able to create on local windows machine, but is there a way to describe different linux host in the Dataobject definition?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

DATAOBJECT is a string represnetation of a fully qualified filename that contains data for the external table, and it is interpreted differently depending on whether or not REMOTESOURCE is specified.

If REMOTESOURCE is not specified for the external table definition, then the file specified by DATAOBJECT is always local to the Netezza host. If REMOTESOURCE is specified, then the filename specified by DATAOBJECT is local to the machine where the external table is created and referenced.

If your Linux "script-host" is using ODBC, JDBC, or nzcli (and nzcli only if you are on very recent releases, 7.2.1 or later) then you can specify the connection type for REMOTESOURCE, and then the path to the filename backing the external table will be on the "script-host" rather than on the Netezza host.

You cannot currently create and use an external table on one system that is not the Netezza host (e.g. your laptop) that references a DATAOBJECT on another system that is not the Netezza hosts (e.g. your "script-host").